# Entity Framework 4: Inheritance and Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, optimistic-concurrency

I'm using AdventureWorks 2008 R2 database and added the BusinessEntity and Person tables to my EDMX. Then I changed the model in which the Person table inherits from the BusinessEntity table. As you may know these two tables have ModifiedDate and rowguid columns so the Person class should not have these properties because it inherits them from the BusinessEntity class.

My question is, how can I modify the model to support inheritance and optimistic concurrency on both Person and BusinessEntity classes/tables on ModifiedDate property/column.

PS. It also get me an error message that I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015358/error-3032-during-ef-4-0-validation).

Thanks